# my $http req data has id's instead of actual data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I'm new to $http request and Node. I'm trying to send the form data to 
the server but the output is just bunch of ids I have no idea where it is coming from.

[Output of my $http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqkE7.png)

[Expanded Results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xviDf.png)

As you can see the id on the above image. But why is the actual data is inside the config.

**HTML Code :**

```
<form ng-model="formData">
  <div class="radio">
   <label>Chat</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chat" ng-model="formData.mgr_chat" ng-true-value="'on'" ng-false-value="'off'">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Controller Code :**

```
$scope.formData = {};

var scrumData = $scope.formData;

$http.post('/writefile', {scrumData})
.then(function(result) {
  console.log('$http Result: ', result);
})
```

**writeFile.js**

```
var json = require('json-update');
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');


http.get('http://localhost:5000/writefile', function(res){
 var data = '';
 res.on('data', function (chunk){
   data += chunk;
 });
 res.on('end', function() {
 console.log(JSON.parse(data));
 //Updating the JSON file

 json.update('./json/catchallfile.json', data)
  .then(function(output) {
    console.log(output);
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: config attribut of response object is just to keep trace of your "body" data provided to your backend. What you try to acheive ?

Comment: Check your server side code to see what it returns for /writefile, The bunch of Ids are created at the node end. Add that code and we might be able to help

Comment: @Yanis-git I'm trying to update a json file with the form data.

Comment: @LasithaPetthawadu I have updated the server code, fyi I'm using 'deployd'

Comment: @Pradeep Why is writefile a Get request? shouldn't it be a POST?

Comment: @LasithaPetthawadu yes, my mistake I'll correct that now,  any idea about the ids? or how to access the data actually